# MySQL docker container crashes

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker

I'm a newbie with Docker and I'm working on a Symfony2 software development project that uses docker with MySQL, nginx and the web app containers in it. I'm constantly being disconnected from MySQL with the following error message :

> DriverException in AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 115:
>   An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (113)

When running the command `docker logs -f project_name_db_1`, it returns the following :

```
$ docker logs -f project_name_db_1
170616  8:08:52 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations 
related to importing and exporting data are disabled
170616  8:08:52 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.54) starting as process 1 
...
170616  8:08:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170616  8:08:52 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170616  8:08:52 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170616  8:08:52 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
170616  8:08:52 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170616  8:08:52 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170616  8:08:52 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170616  8:08:52 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 85948426202
170616  8:08:52  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the 
doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 85948426476
170616  8:08:58  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the 
database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 
76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 
99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
170616  8:08:59  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170616  8:09:00 InnoDB: 5.5.54 started; log sequence number 
85948426476
170616  8:09:00 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; 
port: 3306
170616  8:09:00 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
170616  8:09:00 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
170616  8:09:01  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139850856617728 
in file trx0purge.c line 840
InnoDB: Failing assertion: purge_sys->purge_trx_no <= purge_sys->rseg-    
last_trx_no
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
08:09:01 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this 
binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly 
built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning 
hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 
338512 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find 
out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x7aa245]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x403)[0x677123]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf890)[0x7f31a5807890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f31a493c067]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f31a493d448]
mysqld[0x7f8d78]
mysqld[0x7f90f1]
mysqld[0x8c4986]
mysqld[0x8b9edd]
mysqld[0x7f79e5]
mysqld[0x7edaa8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8064)[0x7f31a5800064]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f31a49ef62d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html 
contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
170616  8:31:44 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations 
related to importing and exporting data are disabled
170616  8:31:44 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.54) starting as process 1 
...
170616  8:31:44 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170616  8:31:44 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170616  8:31:44 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170616  8:31:44 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
170616  8:31:44 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170616  8:31:44 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170616  8:31:44 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170616  8:31:44 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 85943235752
170616  8:31:44  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the 
doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 85943236009
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 134825 log sequence number 
85943236282
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 117255 log sequence number 
85943236539
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 103222 log sequence number 
85943236812
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 129676 log sequence number 
85943237069
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 125568 log sequence number 
85943237342
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 126217 log sequence number 
85943237599
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 117266 log sequence number 
85943237872
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 129677 log sequence number 
85943238139
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 123341 log sequence number 
85943238412
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 134834 log sequence number 
85943238685
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 134835 log sequence number 
85943238942
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 129678 log sequence number 
85943239215
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 120136 log sequence number 
85943239472
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:45  InnoDB: Error: page 126223 log sequence number 
85943240002
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
170616  8:31:46  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the 
database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 170616  8:31:46  InnoDB: Error: page 
132382 
log sequence number 85943239891
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 
85943236009.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 
86 87 
88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
170616  8:31:46  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170616  8:31:47 InnoDB: 5.5.54 started; log sequence number 
85943236009
170616  8:31:47 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; 
port: 
3306
170616  8:31:47 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
170616  8:31:47 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
170616  8:31:47 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@8c2b747d6905' 
ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
170616  8:31:48 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
170616  8:31:48 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.54'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL 
Community 
Server (GPL)
170616  8:43:03  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140615160387328 
in 
file trx0purge.c line 840
InnoDB: Failing assertion: purge_sys->purge_trx_no <= purge_sys->rseg-
>last_trx_no
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-
recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
08:43:03 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this 
binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly 
built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning 
hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=5
max_threads=151
thread_count=2
connection_count=2
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 
338512 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find 
out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x7aa245]
mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x403)[0x677123]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf890)[0x7fe3998dc890]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7fe398a11067]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7fe398a12448]
mysqld[0x7f8d78]
mysqld[0x7f90f1]
mysqld[0x8c4986]
mysqld[0x8b9edd]
mysqld[0x7f79e5]
mysqld[0x7ece0e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8064)[0x7fe3998d5064]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fe398ac462d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html 
contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Any ideas?

The content of my dockerfile is:

```
FROM debian:8

# Install Requirements
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qqy \
    sudo \
    wget \
    curl \
    git \
    apt-utils \
    netcat-openbsd \
    acl \
    && echo "Europe/Paris" > /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure -f 
noninteractive tzdata \
    && echo 'alias ll="ls -lah --color=auto"' >> /etc/bash.bashrc

# Variables Apache
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER  www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE  /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR   /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR  /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR   /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_USER_UID 0

ENV HOME /root

RUN echo "deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all" >> 
/etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all" >> 
/etc/apt/sources.list
RUN wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
RUN cat dotdeb.gpg | apt-key add -

# Java, PHP && Apache
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -qqy --force-yes \
   default-jre \
   php5 \
   php-apc \
   php5-cli \
   php5-xdebug \
   php5-intl \
   php5-mcrypt \
   php5-mysql \
   php5-curl \
   php5-gd \
   apache2 \
   #apache2-mpm-worker \
   apache2-utils \
   libapache2-mod-php5 \
   mysql-client

# Config Apache
ADD conf/apache/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/web.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite \
    && rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default \
    && rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf \
    && rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-available/default \
    && rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl \
    && rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl \
    && rm -rf /var/www/html \
    && a2ensite web.conf

# Config PHP
ADD conf/php5/apc.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/apc.ini
ADD conf/php5/php.ini /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
ADD conf/php5/php.ini /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

# Logs
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/apache2 \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/apache2

# Alias
RUN echo "alias sf='php app/console'" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo "alias sfprod='php app/console --env=prod'" >> /root/.bashrc

# Sources
WORKDIR /var/www

EXPOSE 80

VOLUME ["/var/log/apache2", "/var/www"]

ADD script/start.sh /root/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/start.sh

CMD []
```

My docker-compose-dev.yml looks like this:

```
web:
extends:
    file: docker-compose-common.yml
    service: web
links:
    - db
    - search
    - mailcatcher
environment:
    SYMFONY__CRYPT__KEY:
    SYMFONY__MYAPP__PREFIX: /app_dev.php
    VIRTUAL_HOST: project.dev.domain.fr

db:
    extends:
        file: docker-compose-common.yml
        service: db
    environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: db.project.dev.domain.fr
    ports:
        - "3310:3306"

composer:
    extends:
        file: .namedev/name-common/compose/common.yml
        service: composer

search:
    extends:
            file: docker-compose-common.yml
            service: search
    volumes:
        - "./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
    environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: elk.project.dev.domain.fr
        VIRTUAL_PORT: 9200

mailcatcher:
    image: web/docker-mailcatcher
    environment:
        VIRTUAL_HOST: mailcatcher.dev.domain.fr
        VIRTUAL_PORT: 1080
```

I have another file called docker-compose-common.yml containing this (for the database part):

```
web:
    build: docker
    working_dir: /var/www
    hostname: kgestion
    domainname: kgestion.dev.zol.fr
    command: /root/start.sh
    volumes:
        - ".:/var/www"
        - "./var/logs/web:/var/log/apache2"
    environment:
        CERT_NAME: project
        VIRTUAL_HOST: project.dev.domain.fr,something.dev.domain.fr

        SYMFONY__DATABASE__HOST: db
        SYMFONY__DATABASE__PORT: 3306
        SYMFONY__DATABASE__NAME: project
        SYMFONY__DATABASE__USER: root
        SYMFONY__DATABASE__PASSWORD: project



db:
    image: mysql:5.5
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: project
    volumes:
        - "./data:/var/lib/mysql"

search:
    build: docker/elasticsearch
```

Comment: Dockerfile would be useful, or docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see mysql in there? Is it a different container?

Comment: @delboy1978uk Since I'm a newbie with docker, I would like you to tell me precisely what you want to see. No container is mentioned in the dockerfile which was designed by the lead developer, not me.

Comment: @PatrickBassoukissa please provide the `docker-compose.yml` file (you definitely have one)
then try to recreate your mysql container like this: `docker-compose stop db` and then `docker-compose up`
*BEWARE* ALL THE DATA IN YOUR DATABASE WILL BE THROWN AWAY

Comment: @Serge Velikanov  I have added my docker-compose-dev.yml in the post.

Comment: @delboy1978uk I have added my docker-compose-dev.yml in the post

Comment: @PatrickBassoukissa I believe that you face not a docker issue but issue with your container particularly. try to recreate your database container